# Does the CSRF info change when logging in via ajax request?

Tags: django, django-1.7, django-csrf

I have a form with csrf token that works.

There is also a button to upload a picture via ajax and put the url into a textarea of the first form on the same page. I have some js inplace to set the csrf value and the button also works fine.

If the user is logged in there is absolutely no problem when using first the button to insert the image url and then saving the form.

But when I have a visitor who is not logged in there is a problem: When  he uploads a picture a new account is automatically created and the visitor is logged in without him doing anything.

```
while True:
        try:
          random_password = User.objects.make_random_password()
          random_username = str(uuid.uuid1().hex)[:5]
          new_temp_user = User.objects.create_user(random_username, password=random_password)
        except IntegrityError:
          pass
        else:
          new_user = authenticate(username=random_username,password=random_password)
          login(request,new_user)
          break
```

Since this is done via Ajax he doesn't notice any change to the website he is seeing. Only the url of the uploaded picture gets added to the first form. On the server side he is now a registered user, but he doesn't see it yet. Now when he submits the form the csrf validation fails. The form still has the csrf token in place, but somehow it became invalid.

I suspect that the login process has some influence over the csrf token. Any ideas what I may do about it?

**EDIT:** I checked some more and it seems that the problem is due to the login. Every login seems to change the csrf value. Now when the user gets a login over ajax the token in the form doesn't update. What may be the best way to update it?

Answer (score 2):

The csrf token is rotated when the user logs in. This was added as a security measure in Django 1.5.2 ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.5.2/)).

After the ajax request, you might be able to fetch the new csrf token from the cookie, and update the form in the DOM. Alternatively, you could refresh the page after the user is logged in.

Comment: Well refreshing is not an option as the user already might have put stuff in the form.  I'll have a look into updating the token.